# Function that multiplies element of a list/array by a number in python

Tags: arrays, list, function

I want to create a function that receives an array or a list , and then multiply each element by a Integer number, for example 5.

Def Multiply ( ListOrArray )
...
#Return another list with the same quantity of elements but multiplied by 5.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming in Python makes it quite easy to implement, as you can see in the following snippet:

```py
my_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

results = list(map(lambda x: x*5, my_numbers))

print(results)
```

More information about map, lambda and related functions:

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Map,_Filter,_Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try the following

```
list = [1,2,3]
def multiplier (a):
    b =[]
    for i in list:
        i = i*5
        b.append(i)
    return b
a=list
print(multiplier(a))
```

or

```
def multiplier(*args):
    b=[]
    for a in args:
        a = a*5
        b.append(a)
    return b
print(multiplier(5,6,7))
```